# Cannot delete “Search Service Application” - Event ID: 3355

Tags: search, service-application

I'm unable to remove the "Search Service Application" and I'm open to any ideas.

**This is what I've tried so far (Unsuccessfully):**

- Delete via Central Admin
- Delete via PowerShell 
  `Remove-SPServiceApplication <GUID of the service> -RemoveData`
  `STSADM.EXE -o deleteconfigurationobject -id <GUID of the service>`

Here's the ULS log message from attempting the above:

> Event ID: 3355
>
> Cannot connect to SQL Server. "DBNAME" not found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the SQL Server name "DBNAME" rather than the actual name of your database server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the name for the posting of this question. Should the DBNAME be the name of the server or the name of the DB?

Comment: I can't say without seeing the whole command you executed.